# Ошибка spring bean Maven "Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory"

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'TestBean' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1238)
    at ru.sidorin.springcourse.TestSpring.main(TestSpring.java:8)
```

Что с этим делать? Уже все перерыл и не понимаю, помогите, пожалуйста.

```
package ru.sidorin.springcourse;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class TestSpring {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        TestBean testBean = context.getBean("TestBean", TestBean.class);
        System.out.println(testBean.getName());
        context.close();
    }
}
```

```
package ru.sidorin.springcourse;

public class TestBean {
    private String name;

    public TestBean(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ru.sidorin</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringApp1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringApp1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>https://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringApp1</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="testBean"
          class="ru.sidorin.springcourse.TestBean">
        <constructor-arg value="Roman"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в разных идентификаторах:

- в xml-конфигурации название начинается со строчной буквы `"testBean"`,
- в коде -- с прописной буквы `context.getBean("TestBean", TestBean.class)`.